# Update Data Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firebase and I managed to save Data in my Database, but now I want to update my data as well. I read a lot of stuff and saw a lot of videos, but I could not manage to update it the right way.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profilbearbeiten);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        fullName = findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        email    = findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
        bestätigen = findViewById(R.id.btbestätigen);
        ort = findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        telefonummer = findViewById(R.id.tvTel);
        interessen = findViewById(R.id.tvInt);
        beschreibung = findViewById(R.id.tvBesc);

        bestätigen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfilBearbeiten.this, Profile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                fullName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Benutername"));
                email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("EMail"));
                ort.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Ort"));
                telefonummer.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Telefonnummer"));
                interessen.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Interessen"));
                beschreibung.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Beschreibung"));

            }
        });
```

So here I am calling the Data from the Database and now I want to edit the database:

**pic app and database**
[image]

Comment: None of the code you shared shows how you're writing/trying to write to the database, so it'll be hard to help you with that. I find the examples in this documentation page normally quite helpful to get started with though: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Answer (score 0):

You can use setValue method,like this one

```
FirebaseDatabase  database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = database.getReference();

mDatabaseRef.child("TABLE_NAME").child("TABLE_FIELD").setValue(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use update()

```
public void updateUser(String userID, MAP<String,String> values){
 db.collection("users").document(userID).update(values).
   addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
       Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!");
       }
     })
   .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
     @Override
     public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
       Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e);
       }
     });
 }
```

This example will update the values for the user and will log either is successful or a failure.